# Node.js Routing trouble during HTTP Rest Developement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to build up a MEAN project. Client is done. But from the Server Side, I am not able to make a new insert (it is done with HTTP Post).

Here I show you how I did the index (it is a simply data-listing from my MongoDB) that works. But first, I will show you my data-model and the database:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//My Schema
var Sch = mongoose.Schema(
    {
    titulo: String,
    descripcion: String,
    precio: Number,
    imagen: String} );

//Access to Prueba db 
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/prueba');
//Stablish our model
Camis = db.model('camisetas',Sch);

//Make accesible for other modules
module.exports = Camis;
```

**index.js:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//model with connection
var Camis = require('./models');


//simply list the results

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var a = Camis.find().lean().exec(function(err, results){

    console.log('find DONE'+results.length);
    res.render('index', { camis: results } );

    });
});
//Real model-data work
var camisetas = require('./camisetas');
camisetas.setModel(Camis);
/*
::::::Verbs HTTP:::::
**
**get()-- Mostrar registros
**post()-- Insertar nuevos registros
**put()-- Modificar
**delete()-- Eliminar
*/

router.get('/camisetas', camisetas.index);

//I use it first to create the forms, not posting
router.get('/camisetas/create', camisetas.create);

//The real "post" that cames from create and then, stores the new "Camisetas" object
router.post('/camisetas', camisetas.store);
//Other routes that doesn't matter me
router.get('/camisetas/:id', camisetas.show);

router.get('/camisetas/:id/edit', camisetas.edit);

router.put('/camisetas/:id', camisetas.update);

router.delete('/camisetas/:id', camisetas.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

As you all can see, I have commented where works and my idea of how I would POST.

**camisetas.js**

```js
var Camiseta;


exports.setModel = function(modelo){
   Camiseta = modelo;
};

//index
exports.index = function(req, res){

   Camis.find({}, function(error, result){
      if(error)
         res.send('[ERR] camisetas.js (index)');
      else
         res.render('camisetas/index', { camisetas: result });
    })
};

//create
exports.create = function(req, res){
   res.render('camisetas/save', {
      put: false,
      action: '/camisetas/',
      camiseta: new Camiseta({
         titulo: '',
         descripcion: '',
         precio: 0,
         imagen: ''
      })
   });
};
//save
exports.store = function(req, res){

   var camiseta = new Camiseta({
      titulo: req.body.camiseta.titulo,
      descripcion: req.body.camiseta.descripcion,
      precio: req.body.camiseta.precio,
      imagen: req.body.camiseta.imagen
   });

   camiseta.save(function(error, documento){
      if(error){
         res.send('Error al intentar guardar la camiseta.');
      }else{ 
         res.redirect('/camisetas');
      }
   });
};
exports.show = function(req, res){
   //
};
exports.edit = function(req, res){
   //
};
exports.update = function(req, res){
   //
};
exports.destroy = function(req, res){
   //
};
```

**index.jade:**

```jade
extends layout
block content
  h1 Camisetas
  p
    a(href="/camisetas/create") Crear nueva camiseta
  -if(camis.length > 0)
    table
      thead
        tr
          th Titulo
          th Descripcion
          th 
          th
          th
      tbody
        -each item in camis
          tr
            td #{item.titulo}
            td #{item.descripcion}
            td Ver
            td Editar
            td Eliminar
  -else
    p No existen Camisetas.
```

**save.jade:**

```jade
extends ../layout
block content
  h1 Guardar camiseta
  form(method="post", action="#{action}")
    -if(put)
      input(type="hidden", name="_method", value="PUT")
    label Titulo
    br
    input(type="text", name="titulo", required="required", value="#{camiseta.titulo}")
    br
    label Precio
    br
    input(type="text", name="precio", required="required", value="#{camiseta.precio}")
    br
    label Imagen
    br
    input(type="text", name="imagen", required="required", value="#{camiseta.imagen}")
    br
    label Descripcion
    br
    textarea(name="descripcion", cols="50", rows="5", required="required") #{camiseta.descripcion}
    br
    input(type="submit", value="Guardar")
    a(href="/personajes") Cancelar
```

And finally, the output of Chrome, in the case I try to create and post it (I enter correctly into the forms, when I try to POST it throws the error):

> ```
> Cannot read property 'camiseta' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'camiseta' of undefined
>     at exports.store (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\routes\camisetas.js:36:23)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>     at next (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>     at Function.handle (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
>     at router (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at trim_prefix (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>     at C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>     at next (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>     at expressInit (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
> ```

Comment: For those of you playing along the error occurs on this line: `descripcion: req.body.camiseta.descripcion`, which probably should have been indicated in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're either missing a body parsing middleware (e.g. [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and/or [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)) or the request does not have a body (e.g. it is not an `application/json`, `multipart/form-data`, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request).

Comment: Hi! I have the dependency and the use in my shell dude :/  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Ok, then did you check the request's `Content-Type` (e.g. `console.dir(req.headers['content-type'])`)?